# In-memory metafile is not drawn

Tags: .net, gdi+, metafile

I need to create some in-memory (not file-based) metafiles and display them. In the `OnPaint` handler of a panel on my form I call this code:

```
Metafile metafile;
using( Graphics offScreenGraphics = Graphics.FromHwndInternal( IntPtr.Zero ) )
{
    IntPtr hDC = offScreenGraphics.GetHdc();
    metafile = new Metafile( hDC, EmfType.EmfPlusDual );
    offScreenGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
}

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage( metafile );
graphics.FillRectangle( Brushes.LightYellow, 0, 0, 100, 100 );
graphics.DrawLine( Pens.Red, 50, 50, 100, 100 );

e.Graphics.DrawImage( metafile, 50, 50 );
```

However, nothing is displayed and regardless of what I try to draw in the `metafile`, its `PhysicalDimension` is always something like 35x35, which is too small given that the units are hundredths of a millimeter!

**NOTE:** Of course this is a contrived example, I won't be creating a metafile just to draw some graphic in the same method. I need to pass the metafile around in my application. This is just a simple test to make sure I will be able to draw it with the `DrawImage` method.

Answer (score 2):

OK, that was easy. From my original example I left out details which I thought were unnecessary, such as *disposing the GDI objects I used*. But in case of metafiles, it seems to be **crucial** to dispose the `Graphics` object you are drawing it with. Only after you do that, the metafile is "finished" and you can draw it (it also report a correct `PhysicalDimension`, by the way).

So the above code should be adjusted in this way:

```
using( Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage( metafile ) )
{
    graphics.FillRectangle( Brushes.LightYellow, 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    graphics.DrawLine( Pens.Red, 50, 50, 100, 100 );
}
```

Comment: Yes, Graphics objects must always be created when you're gonna use them and disposed when you're done as they are rendered invalid for each WM_PAINT event that occurs. You can also call its Flush() method before disposing.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the `Flush` tip. I thought there is such a method but I couldn't recall its name.